# Using web services

Tags: android, database, web-services, web

This question is maybe easy or unnecessary for you but I'm stuck here.

I'm trying to make application which store your spending money information. I finished the interface of the app, but the sql part isn't done because i wanna use that sql from internet. As i know, i should use web services ( maybe there is another way ). It should do like add 5 dollar to marketing, add 20 dollar to fuel categories.

1. Is the best way using web service?
2. How am i going to create and use my own db? ( i mean do i create db
   on sql server and upload it to host, or creating db with codes on
   android studio ? )
3. I've looked a lot of web services tutorials, but all of them is very confusing. I need tutorial with very basic explanation. Which tutorial or example do you suggest me?

Comment: try with  https://parse.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should host a SQL database and create a [RESTfull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) HTTP web service to perform your desired functions. Make sure you develop the web service using JSON, since this can be easily parsed and used within Android. This [tutorial](http://coreymaynard.com/blog/creating-a-restful-api-with-php/) should get you started, if you know php. You can of course create the API in the language of your preference.

From your android application you can then send [HTTP requests](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html) to your webservice and parse the JSON response to use it in your API.

Your question is a bit broad, so I hope I provided means to get started. If you have any more specific questions about the above design, feel free to ask them.